# Nodejs fs.createReadStream can't read Firebase Storage download URL "ENOENT: no such file or directory"

Tags: node.js, firebase-storage

The [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) for `fs.createReadStream(path)` says that it can read a URL:

```js
path <string> | <Buffer> | <URL>
```

The documentation shows quotes around the `path`:

```js
fs.createReadStream('/dev/input/event0');
```

But when I put in this Firebase Storage download URL

```js
fs.createReadStream('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/languagetwo-cd94d.appspot.com/o/Users%2FbcmrZDO0X5N6kB38MqhUJZ11OzA3%2Faudio-file.flac?alt=media&token=871b9401-c6af-4c38-aaf3-889bb5952d0e'),
```

I get the error message `ENOENT: no such file or directory`. You can click on the URL and hear that it works:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/languagetwo-cd94d.appspot.com/o/Users%2FbcmrZDO0X5N6kB38MqhUJZ11OzA3%2Faudio-file.flac?alt=media&token=871b9401-c6af-4c38-aaf3-889bb5952d0e

I also tried the Google Storage URI:

```js
fs.createReadStream('gs://languagetwo-cd94d.appspot.com/Users/bcmrZDO0X5N6kB38MqhUJZ11OzA3/audio-file.flac'),
```

That didn't work. Do I have to use `https.request` to make an HTTP GET request?

Here's my full code, copied from the [IBM Cloud Speech-to-Text API docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text/speech-to-text?code=node#recognize-audio):

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const SpeechToTextV1 = require('ibm-watson/speech-to-text/v1');
const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');

const speechToText = new SpeechToTextV1({
   authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({
      apikey: 'my-api-key',
      }),
   url: 'https://api.us-south.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/01010101',
});

var params = {
   audio: fs.createReadStream('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/languagetwo-cd94d.appspot.com/o/Users%2FbcmrZDO0X5N6kB38MqhUJZ11OzA3%2Faudio-file.flac?alt=media&token=871b9401-c6af-4c38-aaf3-889bb5952d0e'),
   contentType: 'audio/flac',
   wordAlternativesThreshold: 0.9,
   keywords: ['colorado', 'tornado', 'tornadoes'],
   keywordsThreshold: 0.5,
};

speechToText.recognize(params)
.then(results => {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
})
.catch(err => {
   console.log('error:', err);
});
```

Comment: If you have an HTTP URL, you should be using an HTTP library to fetch it, such as "request" or "request-promise".  fs isn't going to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the file, you have to open up a write stream, then pipe the output of the http library (axios in this example) to that stream.

This would serve you better:

```js
const Fs = require('fs')  
const Path = require('path')  
const Axios = require('axios')

async function downloadImage () {  
  const url = 'https://unsplash.com/photos/AaEQmoufHLk/download?force=true'
  const path = Path.resolve(__dirname, 'images', 'code.jpg')
  const writer = Fs.createWriteStream(path)

  const response = await Axios({
    url,
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'stream'
  })

  response.data.pipe(writer)

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    writer.on('finish', resolve)
    writer.on('error', reject)
  })
}
```

*[source](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/download-files-images-with-axios-in-node-js)*

Answer (score 1):

If you see [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_url_object_support), it clearly mentions that it only supports `file://` protocol. There is no support for `http/https`.

I wouldn't suggest using `request` or `request-promise` as they have been deprecated. I would recommend using some modern libraries like `got`, `axios` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! `got` isn't going to work because it uses a `function*` generator, and Google Cloud Functions uses an older version of Node without generators. I'll try `axios`.

Answer (score 0):

Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60822895/node-js-confusion-about-buffers-streams-pipe-axios-createwritestream-and-cr) I asked answers this question as well. Axios not only gets the file but also streams it, eliminating the `fs.createReadStream`.